# How do I get an object that will both extend vertically to fill a section AND have a background determined by a formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

**Goal**

Create a table.

---

**Problem**

The first column of the table is text, and sometimes has to extend down to the next line. Meanwhile the other columns need to become gray based on some external conditions. These boxes will also have content, assuming a grey background is not applied.

---

**The Reason I'm Asking**

When I search for an solution to this problem, I am confronted with conflicting answers, telling me to use one or another of options, neither of which fill my requirements.

1. Text fields only extend when their text requires them to, and will not fill a section.
2. Text fields can have their background controlled by a formula.
3. Boxes are able to extend automatically to fill a section.
4. Boxes do not have any properties controllable by formulas.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem at all? I have even seen suggestions to stack objects and suppress them, but this will not work for boxes, which cannot have a formula applied to their suppress.

---

**EXAMPLE:**

[image: CheckTable]

Comment: These boxes will also have content, assuming a grey background is not applied.- Which boxes? Table columns? Are they in boxes? Please add preview with some explanation.

Comment: @JulyOrdinary I've attached an image which I believe will clear up any confusion you may have. Basically, I need to make the columns beyond the first actually work - they must conditionally have content, a background, and must fill the section vertically.

Comment: Well, I understood. The workaround could be to place the same text in this box too and set the text color to transparent or something. In this way, this content box will grow as per the first column.

Comment: @JulyOrdinary that would only work if I made the text fields all the same horizontal length so that they overflow on the same words... It looks like a later version of Crystal Reports may have the solution, though; if so, I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out they eventually fixed this issue in a later version of Crystal Reports:
[image]

This is available in version 13, SP19.